# wine crashes - out of GDI object handles?

Tags: wine

Running a program under wine it crashes after a while with many of the following messages:

> fixme:olepicture:OLEPictureImpl_FindConnectionPoint no connection point for {33ad4f92-6699-11cf-b70c-00aa0060d393}

and

> err:gdi:alloc_gdi_handle out of GDI object handles, expect a crash

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Does it always crash or is this with a particular app? Also there are some things to try in this bug report: https://github.com/kellyelton/OCTGN/issues/795

Comment: this particular app always crashes after a while, where  "after a while" means after using it a while; if you let it be idle it sits there indefinitely.

Comment: What app is it?

Comment: It's called chessimo (a chess training program - very nice, indeed). A demo version is available at http://www.chessimo.com. Caveat: my version is older than the one that can be downloaded now. I once tried to install a newer version, but it told me that it needed whatever .NET so I didn't pursue that further. The interesting thing is: it worked once without trouble (or so I remember it).

Comment: I wanted to try this out for myself to see what's going on. But won't have time until later tonight. I'm in EDT timezone so probably 9pm+.

Comment: Don't worry. Actually, as a user I don't mind the app crashing every 30 minutes or so, it's just annoying. However, having degrees in Computer Science the whole thing infuriates me somewhat.